# Auth with todoist API: invalid_grant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, todoist

I'm adding the ability to post todos to my Todist list via a simple app. At the moment I am getting the response `"error"=>"invalid_grant"` when exchanging my code for an access_token.

I'm unsure exactly what 'invalid_grant' is referring too in this context. Other answers I find seem to be regarding various Google APIs. The [Todoist API documentation](https://developer.todoist.com/#authorization) makes no mention of it.

The post request for token exchange is:

```
uri = URI('https://todoist.com/oauth/access_token')
result = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, client_id: ENV['TODOIST_CLIENT_ID'], client_secret: ENV['TODOIST_CLIENT_SECRET'], code: params[:code])
json_body = JSON.parse(result.body) # <- prints error
```

Any help understanding and solving this is much appreciated.

**Update**

After reading Takahiko Kawasaki's answer, I have updated the request to the following, but have the same error message.

```
uri = URI('https://todoist.com/oauth/access_token')
data = {
  :client_id => ENV['TODOIST_CLIENT_ID'],
  :client_secret => ENV['TODOIST_CLIENT_SECRET'],
  :code => params[:code],
  :grant_type => 'authorization_code',
}
result = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, data)
json_body = JSON.parse(result.body)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. do you have an answer from Todoist team?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following.

```
grant_type: 'authorization_code'
```

See RFC 6749, [4.1.3. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) for details.

---

Additional comment for the revised question.

It seems that the OAuth implementation by Todoist is not mature. I took a look at their [API document](https://developer.todoist.com/#authorization) and soon found some violations against [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

For example, (1) scopes must be delimited by spaces but their document says commas should be used. (2) Their token endpoint does not require the `grant_type` request parameter, which is required by the specification. (3) The value of the `error` parameter in the response from a token endpoint should be `invalid_grant` when the presented authorization code is wrong, but their API document says the value will be `bad_authorization_code`, which is not an official value.

In addition, this is not a violation, but the specification of their API to revoke access tokens implies that they don't know the existence of the official specification for access token revocation, [RFC 7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009).

For public clients (RFC 6749, [2.1. Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)), e.g. smartphone applications, the `client_secret` request parameter of a token endpoint should be *optional*, but their API document says it is *required*.

Because their OAuth implementation does not comply with the specification, it would be better for you to ask Todoist directly.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it makes more sense. Where do I add the `grant_type`? It seems to not work as either a header of query param?

Comment: For example, after `code: param[:code]` like `Net::HTTP.post_form(..., code: params[:code], grant_type: 'authorization_code')`.

Comment: @tonyedwardspz Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. After reading a bit more about Oauth in general I decided it was best to email them anyway. I'll update with an answer when I hear back. Thanks again for your time, I understand this a lot more now :)

Comment: Also, double check to be sure that your `client_id` and `client_secret` are correct. I had miscopied one and was getting the `invalid_grant` error.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the Todoist API (v8) does not require the `grant_type` parameter so this is not currently the issue.

Two possible reasons for receiving the `invalid_grant` error are:

1. The `code` was not used within a certain length of time and has expired
2. The `code` has already been used to generate an access token and so is no longer valid

In both cases, generating a new `code` before making the POST request should sort the problem.

Comment: everytime someones tries to login, I am generating a code (which is getting generated successfully for my client_id). But, after using this code for [this token-exchange-api](https://developer.todoist.com/guides/#step-3-token-exchange), i am getting this error `invalid_grant`.